# Emberjs templateName can't be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm trying to render EmberJS with `application.hbs` in my Rails app but I cannot get it to render on my dashboard page.

Furthermore, when I go to `http://example.com/#/users` I get below error:

```
Assertion failed: You specified the templateName users for <VirtualExhibition.UsersView:ember354>, but it did not exist.
```

I have `user.hbs` in `templates` folder but nothing seems to be rendering at all. Even just plain text string does not appear from the template

Could this be something to do with Ember's naming conventions?

Comment: Have you precompiled your handlebars templates?  If not, that's what you need to do.  Check out https://github.com/yaymukund/grunt-ember-handlebars

Comment: It's Rails app and I have `handlebars-assets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. You need to have `hjs` instead of `hbs` as extensions. This is because `handlebars_assets` gem is conflicting with `ember-rails` gem when compiling handlebars templates.

I found this link extremely helpful:

[Ember Rails Handlebars Assets](http://wjlroe.github.io/2013/02/18/ember-rails-handlebars-assets.html)

I hope this helps developers having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance you meant `users` template? not a `user` template.

This all depends on whether or not you are defining a different template name somewhere else or not.

Comment: No. I have `users.hbs` under `templates` folder. I also have `user.hbs` aswell